# ExtJS 6.7 Modern - Prevent auto completion on a field / inputAttrTpl

Tags: extjs, extjs6, extjs6-modern

To prevent auto completion on a field with classic toolkit I could use [Ext.form.field.Base.inputAttrTpl](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.7.0/classic/Ext.form.field.Base.html#cfg-inputAttrTpl) like this: `inputAttrTpl: 'autocomplete="new-password"'`.

How I can achieve this with modern toolkit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is trivial - modern toolkit provide us with [Ext.field.Text.autoComplete](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.7.0/modern/Ext.field.Text.html#cfg-autoComplete) config.